# How to get expirey date of autoRenewable subscription

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Can anyone tell me how to get expirey date of autorenewable subscription.
Actually i have to check if subscription is still valid after subcription date. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to validate your base 64 receipt in apple server. If apple server respond with status key with value 0 then you will find latest_receipt_info key. This key consist all the information regarding auto renewal subscription. You can get expiry date information in expires_date key.

Comment: Thankyou, i am succeded to get expirey date. But the date is date of subscription in "expirey date". I am using expirey date. and some hours are change can u tell me in sandbox testing the 6 months subscription is 6 hours time

Comment: @Gaurav In sandbox environment :1 week = 3min, 1 month = 5 min, 2 month = 10 min, 3 month =15 min, 6 month = 30 min and 1 year = 1 hr. So if you subscribe in 6 month subscription in every 30 min your subscription will be auto renew for about 6 times then apple won't renew it and it gets expired. Hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you this easy, lightweight framework:

https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit

```
let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .production, sharedSecret: "your-shared-secret")
SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let receipt):
        let productId = "com.musevisions.SwiftyStoreKit.Subscription"
        // Verify the purchase of a Subscription
        let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifySubscription(
            ofType: .autoRenewable, // or .nonRenewing (see below)
            productId: productId,
            inReceipt: receipt)

        switch purchaseResult {
        case .purchased(let expiryDate, let items):
            print("\(productId) is valid until \(expiryDate)\n\(items)\n")
        case .expired(let expiryDate, let items):
            print("\(productId) is expired since \(expiryDate)\n\(items)\n")
        case .notPurchased:
            print("The user has never purchased \(productId)")
        }

    case .error(let error):
        print("Receipt verification failed: \(error)")
    }
}
```

as found in the SwiftyStoreKit-Documentation

I hope that helps you.
If, it would be great if you could accept my answer :)

Comment: i am succeded to get expirey date. But the date is date of subscription in "expirey date". I am using expirey date. and some hours are change
can u tell me in sandbox testing the 6 months subscription is 6 hours time>